# How do I call a VBA function through .Net Interop

Tags: c#, .net, vba, interop

In VBA/VB6 I can call a function or a subroutine like so:

```
Call myFunction
```

I am plugging into an Access application from .Net like so:

```
using MSAccess = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application;

var access = new MSAccess();
access.OpenCurrentDatabase(@"C:\myDatabase.accdb");

access. //Here I can more or less type my VBA code the same way I can natively

access.CloseCurrentDatabase();
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(access);
```

What do I put after the dot to call `myFunction` via MS Access Interop?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Duly noted, it's more muscle memory than anything, I will keep that in mind for the future!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if [Application.Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221582%28v=office.11%29.aspx) does what you want, based on the example given in the link.

**EDIT**: Also, [`DoCmd.RunMacro`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220713%28v=office.11%29.aspx) should work.